# Elastix not found using pip

Tags: registration, elastix

I am having troubles with installing Elastix/simpleElastix on my windows pc using pip:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?

Kind regards,
Jesse

Comment: You're probably going to need to provide more detail. Is that screen shot the only thing you've tried? Have you read any documentation on installing Elastix/simpleElastix on Windows. The error message says it is looking for a macosx version, but you are not on macosx.

Comment: I've also tried to download the executables for windows from [link](http://elastix.isi.uu.nl/download.php). Filled in the form and clicked on 'Download', but then nothing happened. So I tried the 'Download anonymously' button and then I did get the executables. However, when I try to execute them a window appears only very briefly and nothing else happens.